# When pressing a button on a webpage loads a new URL in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

At the following web address: h`ttps://www.sky.com/new-search/chernobyl?q=chernobyl` is a button called `Episodes`. I have determined from Google Chrome developer tools, that this is represented by:

```
<button role="tab" type="button" id="tabs-id_2474-link-1" class="c-tabs__link" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs-id_2474-article-1" data-test-id="episodes-tab-button">Episodes</button>
```

...I've also managed to find from the 'Sources' tab of dev tools that the Javascript for mouse clicks is `webpack:///./src/builders/click.js?388e`.

The effect of pressing the `Episodes` button is that the URL of the page changes from `https://www.sky.com/new-search/chernobyl?q=chernobyl` to `https://www.sky.com/new-search/chernobyl/episodes/season-1/episode-0?q=chernobyl` and the page changes to show episodes from the series and a synopsis for that episode.

The bit I am missing though, is now does the mouse click Javascript trigger the loading of this second URL? I need to be able to capture somehow the new URL, or even better the full source code for the second URL...

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this not your code?  If not, how are you injecting code into this page?  Via extension?

Comment: This is not my code no, this is just me trying to get a URL out a page on the web...

Comment: So, where are you running your code that you want to use to track URL changes?  Also note that a lot of pages use the history API to update the URL, so the underlying page itself may not be changing.

Comment: I was planning on writing something in Python for this. Im not a web developer, but am pretty good with Python, so some of your terminology is not familiar to me...

Comment: I'm just trying to work out what I need to interrogate for now though from the website

Comment: Ah, got it, so you want to use Python to scrape the page and then get the URL for a particular button?  That's not possible without running a browser engine, for modern client-side web applications like this.  For a specific site, you could write specific code for it to figure it out... but more generically, you'll need a whole browser engine running.

Comment: by browser engine, do you mean something like selenium?

Comment: Sort of.  I mean that you need Blink, WebKit, etc., and then control it with your Python script.  I used to use PhantomJS for things, but it is no longer an active project.  Chromium Embeded Framework is popular, but I don't know what sort of bindings are available for Python, sorry.

Comment: ok, thanks for the input. i have some reading to do then it appears. do you have any links you could recommend for getting started?

Comment: I just Googled and found this:  https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython

Comment: perfect, thanks. lot's of reading to do, but im looking for a challenge. appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client-side applications can basically do whatever they want, in terms of navigation.  There is no standard mechanism, outside of a normal link `<a>`.

What they're probably doing is updating the existing page, and updating the URL to retain the state.  That is, when you click the button, their code goes off and fetches some data from the server, then creates elements on the page based on that data.  The actual original HTML page (and context) stays the same, but it can be modified with fresh data.  The URL can be updated with the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

If you know something about the web application you're trying to inspect, you can write code for it specifically.  For example, if you know that the application always fetches data from `https://api.example.com/some-data`, then you can skip the whole web page ordeal and hit the API directly.

If you need a more generic solution, the only thing you can really do is run a whole browser engine, through [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) or similar.  This allows the web application to run as it normally would.  Then, on URL change, you can inspect the DOM with your own code.